# Setting the bash SHELL for remote openSSH connections?

Tags: shell, ssh, freebsd, openssh

I am connected to a Freebsd 10 `-STABLE` server with `SSH` from my office box but when I trying to work inside the session I encounter these problems:

- although I did `chsh` for every user in said server to `/usr/local/bin/bash`; whenever I ssh to server I get:
  ``` sh (the default Bourne shell in FreeBSD) supports command-line editing.  Just
  ``set -o emacs'' or ``set -o vi'' to enable it. ```
- in my ssh session I can't go to end of a line by `End` key or beginning of a line by `Home` key. instead I get `~` character. all and all the environment I feel in the `SSH session` is primitive and hard to navigate.

the `echo $SHELL` returns `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

the `ps -ef|grep $$` returns:
`2010  0  S    0:00.03 TERM=xterm PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/s`

and

`echo $0` returns `su`

Comment: @michas I edited the question

Comment: I'm not sure whether you have set /usr/loca/bin/bash as your default shell or are you currently running it on command line ?

Comment: @XTian i change the shell by `chsh` for every user I have on that server and when i connect to server by vSphere Client i am in bash environment.

Comment: Please add the output of `getent passwd $USER`. Are you able to use `chsh`? Does `/etc/shells` contain bash?

Comment: You said `whenever I ssh to server I get:
sh (the default Bourne shell in FreeBSD) ...`. Is that message in `/etc/motd`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick no there is nothing like that in `/etc/motd`

Comment: @michas I did your command. It returned a couple of line at the end of it was `&:/root:/usr/local/bin/bash `

Comment: @r004 the `getent` command should output exactly one line. (be sure to replace $USER with your username, if your shell does not take care of this.)

Comment: @michas I did. I pasted the last bit above for you. It is right above your question. It seems shell is bash but I can't any of the functionality I have in normal bash env.; or even the bash env. that I have access to it with the help of vSphere Client.

Comment: General hint for question: Add some explicit question (something ending in a question mark) to your question. Describe exactly what you where doing. copy&paste the exact command output in your question. Also it is usually better to update your question than to only hide important information in answer comments.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [FreeBSD documentation](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/shells.html) a regular `chsh` should do:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

The output about "... supports command line editing ..." probably comes from a [fortune](http://ftp.tw.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-stable/src/games/fortune/datfiles/freebsd-tips) configured at your startup script. (It displays a random tip at login.)

Comment: but it doesn't affect the remote SSH connection

Comment: I do not understand your exact problem. SSH should start exactly the shell configured by `chsh` and displayed by `getent`. (see my comment above.)

Comment: so there is something wrong at the client side?

Comment: What is the exact ssh command you use to connect? What remote user are you logging into? What shell is configured for that user? Are there any remote startup scripts for that shell, which output that message or start even another shell? Did you set up the FreeBSD server by yourself? Did you talk to the admins otherwise?

Comment: i use putty; I login to a user with `sudo` privilages; `/usr/local/bin/bash/` is for all user; No remote startup-scripts; Yes I set the FreeBSD server by myself.

Comment: Try to find out what shell you are running. `echo $0`, `echo $SHELL` or `ps -ef|grep $$` might help you with that. I am pretty sure you are already running bash as a shell.

Comment: If you do not run `sudo` after connecting to the FreeBSD system, do the editing characters still work? If you type control-A, does the cursor go to the beginning of the line?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick , actually It does. thank you. but why home and end keys don't work. It must be the putty of some other client side problem; Yes?

Comment: It sounds like putty is sending characters for the home and end keys that do not match the characters for the terminal type that bash has been instructed to respond to (xterm). I defer to the putty experts for advice.